# shared_ptr to map populated in a method comes back empty in the caller

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, stdmap

I am initializing a shared_ptr to map in a separate function called GetData. This map is passed as argument to GetData function. However, in the main, map comes back empty after the call to GetData function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

void  GetData(std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> data);

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> data2 = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>();
    GetData(data2);
    return 0;
}

void GetData(std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> data)
{

    data = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>
        (std::initializer_list<std::map<int, int>::value_type>{
            { 1, 2 },
            { 5, 6 },
            { 4, 5 }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
If I re-write method as follows while parameter still not passed by reference, I do get map populated in the main after call to GetData method.

```
void GetData(std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> data)
{
    data->insert(std::pair<int, int>(1,2));
    data->insert(std::pair<int, int>(45, 2));
}
```

Comment: `data = ...` Remember, unless you use a reference, objects ere passed by *value* in C++.  Change the argument type, or better still, lose it entirely, use the return value of your function instead, and take advantage of RVO.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated my question with an alternate solution where I pass the shared_ptr of map by value but can get the data in the main. Any idea why it works in the second method?

Comment: You completely replace the shared pointer in the fist method with a new object. If you make two objects then both pointers can be pointing at the same object right? The new object you make in the function is  destroyed when the function ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `data` by reference:

```
void GetData(std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>>& data)
```

Or preferably, so it makes more sense as function that "gets" and returns something, have the value returned

```
std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> GetData()
{

    return std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>
        (std::initializer_list<std::map<int, int>::value_type>{
            { 1, 2 },
            { 5, 6 },
            { 4, 5 }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks @selbie. I updated my question with another solution where I can pass the map still not by reference and can get the data in the caller. Any idea why it works in that scenario?

Comment: Because you're dereferencing the pointer, instead of assigning to the pointer. The shared_ptr is being passed by value, so modifying the passed value itself has no effect on the map the shared_ptr is referencing. But you can dereferenced a map from any shared_ptr that refers to the map, the original or the copy of the shared ptr.